# How to zoom to current location on map with Skobbler

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I want to zoom to current user's location upon initialising SKMap.
Right now I don't know if it's even possible (even though it's impossible that it's impossible) but I fail to find the way through documentation.

Only thing I found is method for android

mapView.setZoom(int);

But there is nothing like it for iOS.

How can I zoom to the users current location then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply create a region for your map to focus onto:

```
SKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5233, 13.4127);
region.zoomLevel = 17;
mapView.visibleRegion = region;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used SKMap before, but, yes you can simply obtain the user's location in iOS using CLLocationManager. I assume there's a function in SKMap by which you can zoom to a particular set of coordinates, to which you can simply pass the coordinates obtained from CLLocation Manager.

Comment: That's the thing. I cannot find a way to zoom in, I already have coordinates